# Problem creating a new laravel project "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create new laravel project, but it says the following when I run `laravel new laragigs`

```
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./laragigs"
    Installing laravel/laravel (v9.5.2)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v9.5.2): Extracting archive
    Created project in C:\Users\Omistaja\Desktop/laragigs
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v9.36.4, ..., v9.51.0] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.12.2].
    - laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., v9.36.3] require league/flysystem ^3.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.12.2].
    - league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.12.2] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., v9.51.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\php\php-8.2.2-nts-Win32-vs16-x86\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
PS C:\Users\Omistaja\Desktop>
```

What hould I do?

Comment: Find a Hammer, find `php-fileinfo` and smash the hell out of it!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` to php.ini worked.